# When I remove and then, add a row on tableview, it adds the removed row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to let the user edit a tableview, which is adding and removing rows.

That works. But if I remove a row and then add, the inserted row has the info of the deleted row. Is literally the deleted row.

What I am doing wrong?

```
@IBAction func addArticle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    numItems += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numItems - 1, section: 0)
    myTableView.beginUpdates()
    myTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    myTableView.endUpdates()
    view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func removeArticle(sender: UIButton) {
    numItems -= 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    myTableView.beginUpdates()
    myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    myTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

The datasource and delegate for the tableview as follows:

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numItems
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        numItems -= 1
        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if firstUse{
        firstUse = false
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    if firstUse{
        //setting cell
        //...
        cell.name.isEnabled = false
        cell.name.textColor = UIColor.gray
        cell.unit.text = //something
    }

    return initCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
}

func initCell(cell: MyTableViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) -> MyTableViewCell {
    cell.name.inputAccessoryView = addDoneToolbarKeyboard()
    cell.amount.inputAccessoryView = addDoneToolbarKeyboard()

    cell.name.filterStrings(getFilteredBy())
    cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.minusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.removeArticle), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.name.itemSelectionHandler = { filteredResults, itemPosition in
        //irrelevant code
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The documentation on insertRows (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) says this method calls the relevant datasource and delegate methods. Can you add your datasource delegate information? Do you use cellForRow (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)?

Comment: Updated info. Is that the one you are taking about?

Comment: As always, `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` is syntactic sugar in this case. It has no effect at all.

Comment: Not sure what you meant. But it adds and removes rows. On all the places where I have searched, they use begin and end. Is not this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct (although it causes no harm) . There are many tutorials which suggest this nonsense. Both methods are required if **multiple** `insert/delete/move` operations are performed **simultaneously**, only there. In your case it's pointless.

Comment: Yeah I was really surprised to see a call to insertRows. Are there really tutorials promoting this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a use of `indexPath` in your `initCell` method (other than setting cell.minusButton.tag). Typically you use the indexPath as an index to an array of data, or something similar along those lines. I would be able to tell for sure if I could see where your table gets its data, but judging from that and the way you call `names = Array()` and `amounts = Array()`, I'm guessing that you are not updating your data model when you add something to the table. The table dequeues the cell and gets the deleted data. Since the data model feeding the cell is not updated, it creates the same cell and displays it

Comment: The thing is, the user adds rows on the tableview that contains textFields to input text (that is why I am not filling the tableview with info, because the user inputs it). After a few types, the user can select from the filtered array. After that, the textfield is disabled.

Comment: So, can I add a brand new row?

Comment: Ok, I'm following along. Now where are you storing information regarding user input (i.e. the user's array selection or the value in the text field)?

Comment: Each time the user input text and select it from the filtered data, I get certain info. After user click save, i send it to the server.

Comment: I did not put it on the question due to irrelevance regarding the question itself. The thing is, when I add a row, it adds removed items. I don't know why nor if there is a method for inserting brand new rows.

Comment: You're sending the new info to the server, but are you then retrieving a fresh copy from the server when you show the table? Are you also saving it in the app somewhere? Or are you only sending it to the server (in which case the tableview has no idea about the new info)?

Comment: Mmm... let us say, I am not sending anything to the server. The thing is, when I add a row, is empty (the way I want). But if I remove and add a row, it removes and adds the exact same row (same text, same configuration like enabled/disabled, etc.)

Comment: Does replacing `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell` with `let cell = MyTableViewCell()` do anything?

Comment: It crashes. I don't know if is because I don't have a .xib or because is not registered as cell. Actually is as prototype cell. Could it be because of that?

Comment: I created my nib and registered my cell, removed the prototype cell and still crashes...